# Prime Divisors of $x^2 + 1$

Tags: number-theory, functions, prime-factorization

If $x$ is even and $f(x)=x^2 + 1$ is indeed composite, are the prime divisors of $f(x)$ congruent to $1$ mod $4$?

Comment: f(3) = 10 and 2 is a prime divisor of 10.

Comment: @jevie: What is this "oh I forgot..."? Why don't you edit it out, and make the question statement current now that you have remembered something.

Comment: The answer is yes. If you want a proof, it can be found in your typical elementary number theory textbook. Main relevant lemma: if $p\equiv3\pmod4$ and $p\mid(a^2+b^2)$, then $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$.

Comment: Do you know a link about the proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume $p$ is a prime divisor of $n^2 + 1$ for $n$ even.  Clearly $p$ must be odd, and we want to show that $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.

One "big hammer" approach is to use quadratic residues.  Note that if $p$ divides $n^2 + 1$, then $n^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$, so $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$.

[Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) says that $a$ is a quadratic residue mod prime $p$ exactly when:

$$ a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \pmod{p} $$

For the special case $a=-1$ this says $-1$ is a quadratic residue precisely when $(p-1)/2$ is even. That is, not only is $p$ an odd number, but $p-1$ is a multiple of four, i.e. $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ as we wanted to show.

This special case was already known to Fermat, as described by [this extended classroom note on quadratic reciprocity](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400qrlaw.pdf) by Pete L. Clark.